# Why do flashbot transactions have gas fees?

Tags: flashbots, mev

From reading [the docs](https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/searchers/advanced/coinbase-payment) it seemed to be that instead of setting a maximum gas fee on a transaction, we could use this function to tip the miner. However, looking at flaashbot transactions it seems like they do both, tip the miner, and have a gas fee, like in [this example](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8b2ffd6a24dad16a0b42c70b03a7edfef758263a0bd328f4536c0508b60fee36). Do I missunderstand something?

Also, if the tip can be set based on if a transaction was profitable or not, how come there are lossy arbitrage attempts on the blockchain?